# How can I create a form for that is populated with the current data in the database in django?

Tags: django, django-forms

I am new to Django and I am using 1.7.  I am looking for an example, on how to create a form that is populated with the current values which are stored.   This way the user can see the forms current values and just modify the the ones they want.  Then click save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about values stored on a model, you can prepopulate a ModelForm using `instance`:

```
#######forms.py#############
class ArticleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['title']

#######views.py################
#create a normal ModelForm without any pre-populated values
blank_form = ArticleForm()

#create a ModelForm pre-populated with a specific object. first, get that object
article = Article.objects.get(pk=1)
form = ArticleForm(instance=article)
```

Taken from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: I created a model class called GeneralConfiguration and it has a long list of configurations.  I defaulted some of them in the models file.  I created one row of the configurations in the admin.  I don't want the user to add rows to the table, just modify the existing row.  So when the user comes in to modify the row, I want the form to have the database values in the form.

Comment: If you want your user to be able to modify those certain values, then when you create your ModelForm be sure to list those values as the ones you want accessible in the `Fields` list. In your view, you will get the object you wish to modify and create your form using `(instance=object_to_edit)`. When you visit the page, the fields of the form will be pre-populated with whatever values are stored for that object in the database. If you make changes and submit the form, you can process that request using `form.save()` to edit the object in question.

Comment: Does this give me the instance?   general_config_list = GeneralConfiguration.objects.all().order_by("-created_timestamp")[0]

Comment: That gives you a queryset that includes all of your `GeneralConfiguration` objects. You would need to access one individual object within that queryset, declare that object as the instance you want to work with, and then make your edits using the ModelForm. If you want to do this with a bunch of objects at once, you may want a ModelForm Factory rather than just a single form. Check the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.modelform_factory

Comment: I will most likely need a ModelForm Factory when I do the customers section. I will most likely make these forms more complicated.

Comment: I just noticed the [0] on your query! sorry. By using the index value like that, yes, you will get the first item in that queryset. You can also use .first() to get that item by itself rather than loading a full queryset then accessing one item.

Comment: I notice that it is creating records.  I want it to update the existing record. How is that done?

Comment: if request.POST:
        form = GeneralConfigurationUpdateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "You updated was the CES configuration successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect('generalconfig/update/')
        else:
            messages.add_message(request, messages.ERROR, "Your update failed. Please open a ticket with support")

Comment: You are putting (request.POST) when you PROCESS the form, so add the instance argument here too. When you first instantiate the form, you should put (instance=object) there by itself. This is in your view when you are first making the form to show your user - NOT when you are processing it after the user has sent a POST request. In my example code, both 'form' and 'blank_form' are created to service the initial GET request. Without the instance argument, the form makes new models. With it, it edits the instance you indicate. Check the linked docs for exact syntax.